# Spring boot. Circular @Import of main class when run via PropertiesLauncher

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot version is 2.0.4. Code of my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

When i try to run the application via PropertiesLauncher:

```
java -cp App.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLaucnher
```

I got the error:

```
1842 [main] WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: A circular @Import has been detected: Illegal attempt by @Configuration class 'App' to import class 'App' as 'App' is already present in the current import stack [App->App->App]
Offending resource: class path resource [com/example/App.class]
1856 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: A circular @Import has been detected: Illegal attempt by @Configuration class 'App' to import class 'App as 'App' is already present in the current import stack [App->App->App]
Offending resource: class path resource [com/example/App.class]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:72)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:552)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:302)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:589)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$900(ConfigurationClassParser.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:804)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.handle(ConfigurationClassParser.java:759)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:565)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:302)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:589)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$900(ConfigurationClassParser.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:804)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:774)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
        at com.example.App.class.main(App.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:593)
```

What i should do to avoid this circular exception and why it happen?

P.S. I need run this program via PropertiesLauncher.

Comment: What are you trying to do? or what do you need to do? because maybe we can find another way to doit

Comment: This doesn't look like the way you invoke the PropertiesLauncher...not at all...

Comment: @Marco i want add external jar's in classpath, to do this i use run via PropertiesLauncher, it has option -Dloader.path to add additional jar's (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html)

Comment: @Makoto and like what?

Comment: @hungryangry: Show your code.

Comment: @mentallurg i showed, it all i have for now

Comment: @hungryangry: Show MANIFEST.MF.